Finding a Matrix $M$ such that $M^{2}$Equals a Specific Matrix
I’m currently working on a problem and could really use some help. The question is as follows:
Is there a matrix $ M \in \mathcal{M}_3(\mathbb{C}) $such that $$ M^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$?
I tried approaching the problem by considering a general $3 \times 3$ matrix ( M ) with entries ( a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i ) (i.e., $$ M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix} $$) and attempted to solve the resulting system of equations after squaring it. However, the system became too complex to handle.
Then, I tried a different approach by experimenting with matrices that only contain 0s and 1s, hoping to find a solution through trial and error. Unfortunately, this method didn’t seem promising either, as I’m not confident it would help me find all possible solutions.
I’m stuck at this point and would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this problem. Is there a specific method or trick that could simplify finding such a matrix $ M$?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Hint: What is the characteristic equation of $M$?

@EricTowers A matrix is diagonalizable if each block in its Jordan form has no nilpotent part. But clearly we are given a $3\times 3$ Jordan form, with 0's on the diagonal. (Put another way, the eigenvalues of $M$ are all 0, so your $D = 0 $, which then makes $M=0$ but that's a contradiction.) So I don't see how your comment will apply here.

@EricTowers No, it's much more nuanced than that. EG $N = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \ 0 & 0 & 0 \ 0 & 0 & 0 \ \end{pmatrix} $ has a square root, even though it is nilpotent. (Correct me if I'm wrong) Your comment implies that $N$ does not have a square root. $\quad$ The classification for a nilpotent matrix to have a square root, is that you must be able to pair up the Jordan blocks such that their dimension differs at most 1, with possibly an isolated 1-bock. So the 3-block (this question) has no root, but the 1-block + 2-block (my example) has a root.

much simpler approach: you know $\text{rank}\big(M^2\big)=2$ so what would $\text{rank}\big(M\big)$ be?

@CalvinLin : Some day I'll get my head wrapped around defective matrices; apparently today is not yet that day.

@user8675309 : "You mention that since the rank of $^{2}$ is 2, it should lead to a certain rank for . However, I'm not quite sure how to determine the rank of M from this information.

@HenryD you should be able to tell me why you cannot have $\text{rank}\big(M\big) \in\big{0,1,3\big}$ and then make an attempt to explain why $\text{rank}\big(M\big)=2$ can't work either

After analyzing, I realize that for me you're correct: rank() can't be 0, 1, or 3 for the reasons you mentioned. Even with rank(M)=2, it seems difficult to match the given $^{2}$matrix due to the lack of consistent Jordan blocks but I'm not sure how to demonstrate it.

I did not mention any reasons for why $\text{rank}\big(M\big) \not\in\big{0,1,3\big}$ -- I said you should be able to tell me them and you still have not.  You also need to use tags like @HenryD to notify whom you are commenting to in general comments -- the OP is always notified but others typically are not.

$M^4.M=M.M^4$ gives $b=c=f=0.$ The rest is obvious.

I think you can simply use that such $M$ is necessarily  nilpotent, hence $M^3$ should be $0$ but from  $M^2=N$ where $N^2\neq 0$ you derive a contradiction.

Thank you for the explanation, Fred. I understand that  being nilpotent implies
$^{3}=0$ , and how that leads to a contradiction with  $^{2}=$ ?
However, I’m still a bit confused about how we can definitively conclude that there isn't any Matrix like that. Could you clarify the contradiction ?

@HenryD $M^4=M^3\cdot M=0\ne N^2=M^4$.

You're welcomed Henry. Alex Ravsky answered perfectly to your question.

Since matrix multiplication is associative, we have
$M.(M.M)=(M.M).M$
and hence,
$$M.M^2=M^2.M.$$
By OP's approach, we perform the matrix multplications on both sides
$$\tiny\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0& 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 &0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0& 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} b & c& 0 \\ e & f & 0 \\h&i&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0& 0 \\ a& b& c \\ d & e & f \end{pmatrix}$$
and get the following conditions on $M$: $b=c=f=0$, $a=e=i$, $h=d.$
Therefore, $M$ must be in the form:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0& 0 \\ d & a & 0 \\ g& d & a\end{pmatrix}.
$$
But, then
$$M^2=\small\begin{pmatrix} a^2 & 0& 0 \\ 2ad & a^2 & 0 \\ d^2+2ag & 2ad &a^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0& 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\
$$
is a contradiction, since $a^2=0$ and $2ad=1$ can not be true at the same time. So, there can not be such a matrix.
